# How to release memory for SkypeClass or any com component c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using SKYPE4COMLib;

public partial class HowToAddComComponet : System.Web.UI.Page, IDisposable
{
    SkypeClass _skype;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _skype = new SkypeClass();
        _skype.Attach(7, false);

        IEnumerable<SKYPE4COMLib.User> users = _skype.Friends.OfType<SKYPE4COMLib.User>();
        var userss = users.Where(u => u.OnlineStatus == TOnlineStatus.olsOnline)
            .OrderBy(u => u.FullName)
            .ToList();
        foreach (var item in userss)
        {
            string fullName = item.FullName;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Skype com library in my web project and I want to free(release) Skype memory after use.Can any one please let me know how do I achieve this with the help of IDisposable.
Many thanks,

Comment: You inherit from `IDisposable` interface override `Dispose()` method and release your memory there. I mean check documentation on SkypeClass can me that you should call `Dispose()` or other method for this case and when you use your class wrap it with `using()`

Comment: `using (DisposableObject tmp = DisposableObject.AcquireResource()) {
    // Do something with tmp
}
// At this point, tmp.Dispose() will automatically have been called
// BUT, tmp may still a perfectly valid object that still takes up memory`

Answer (score 0):

You can only dispose instances that implement the IDisposable interface.

**To dispose a class you do this:**

```
instance.Dispose();
```

or like this:

```
using(MyClass instance = new MyClass())
{
    // Your cool code.
}
```

that will translate at compile-time to:

```
MyClass instance = null;    

try
{
    instance = new MyClass();        
    // Your cool code.
}
finally
{
    if(instance != null)
        instance.Dispose();
}
```

**You can implement the IDisposable interface like this:**

```
public class SkypeClass : IDisposable
    {
        private bool disposed;

        /// <summary>
        /// Construction
        /// </summary>
        public SkypeClass ()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Destructor
        /// </summary>
        ~SkypeClass ()
        {
            this.Dispose(false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The dispose method that implements IDisposable.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The virtual dispose method that allows
        /// classes inherithed from this one to dispose their resources.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing"></param>
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // Dispose managed resources here.
                }

                // Dispose unmanaged resources here.
            }

            disposed = true;
        }
    }
```